# Resource Optimization: which one to use Knapsack, brute-force or any other approach?

Tags: node.js, algorithm, optimization, brute-force, knapsack-problem

In a resource allocation problem i have ***n*** bucket sizes and ***m*** resources. Resources should be allocated to buckets in such a way that there will be max utilization. I need to write algorithm in **Node js**

Here's the problem: Let's say i have 2 buckets of sizes 50 and 60 respectively. Resource sizes are 20, 25, 40.  Following is the more proper representation with possible solutions:

**Solution 1**:

### | Bucket Size | Resource(s) allocated | Utilization |

|             50             |                       20, 25                   |    45/50 = 0.9    | 
|             60             |                          40                      |  40/60 = 0.667  | 
Total Utilization in this case is  >1.5

**Solution 2**:

### | Bucket Size | Resource(s) allocated | Utilization |

|             50             |                          25                      |    25/50 = 0.5    | 
|             60             |                       20, 40                   |    60/60 = 1.0    | 
Total Utilization in this case is  1.5

**Inference:** 
-- **Knapsack** approach will return Solution 2 because it will do optimization based on higher bucket size.
-- **Brute-Force** approach will return both the solutions. One concern with this approach i have is; given that i have to use Node js and it is single threaded, i am little skeptic about performance when *n* (buckets) and *m* (resources) will be very large.

Will Brute-Force would do just fine or is there a better way/algorithm with which i can solve this problem? Also, is the concern which I've cited above is valid in any sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Knapsack problem (and this is knapsack problem) is NPC, which means, you can find solution only by brute-force or with alghoritms which  have O-complexity same as bruteforce, but can be better in average case...

> it is single threaded, i am little skeptic about performance when n
>   (buckets) and m (resources) will be very large.

I am not sure, if you know how thing works. If you do not create child threads and handle them (which is not that easy), every standard language will work in one thread, therefore in one processor. And if you want more processors that much, you can create child threads even in Node.Js.
Also in complexity problems, it does not matter, if solution takes multiple-time more, if the "multiple" is constant. In your case, I suppose the "multiple" means 4, if you have quad-core.

There are two good solutions :

1)Backtracking - it is basically advanced brute-force mechanism, which can in same cases return solution much faster.

2)Dynamic programming - If you have items with relatively low-values, then while classic brute-force is not able to find solution for 200 items in the expected time of universe itself, the dynamic approach can give you solution in (mili)seconds.